# Tracking User Sessions across a website in R

Tags: r, purrr, user-tracking, rparallel

I am looking for help with creating and tracking user sessions and activities within sessions using R. At a high level I have a column of user Ids and a column of timestamps.

For each user ID I want to calculate the time difference between timestamps and use that to assign a session number based on a time limit value. (i.e. the first timestamp for the user gets a session number of 1. If the next time stamp is < 30 minutes later, the session number would remain as 1, otherwise it would be incremented to 2, and so on.)

Once a session number is assigned for each user action observation I then want to sequence the activities within each session. The first observation for each session would have an activity number of 1, the second observation within the session would have an activity number of 2 and so on. When the session number changes (or the user ID changes) the activity number would reset back to 1.

I have the following repro which does what I am looking for however, this code is very slow on my full dataset (1.4 million rows). In particular, the calls to `difftime` and the for loops are very slow. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this and am open to multiple ideas. Perhaps there is a way to do this without for loops using purrr or perhaps this is an excellent use case for a parallel library. Happy to hear any suggestions for how to make this process easier.

```
library(tidyverse)

session_time_limit <- 30

x <- tibble(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
       Date = c(as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:12 UTC"), #a1
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:30 UTC"), #a2
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:57:12 UTC"), #a3
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:59:12 UTC"), #a4
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 20:11:12 UTC"), #b1
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 20:42:12 UTC"), #b2
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:15:42 UTC"), #c1
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:17:12 UTC"), #c2
                as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:20:13 UTC"))) #c3

x <- x %>% 
  arrange(ID, Date) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(tdiff = difftime(Date, lag(Date), units = "mins"),
         session_number = 1,
         activity_within_session = 1)

for(i in seq(2, nrow(x))) {
  if(!is.na(x$tdiff[i]) &
     #     x$ID[i] == x$ID[i-1] &
     x$tdiff[i] > session_time_limit)
  {
    x$session_number[i] = x$session_number[i-1] + 1
  } else if(!is.na(x$tdiff[i]) &
            x$ID[i] == x$ID[i-1] &
            x$tdiff[i] <= session_time_limit)
  {
    x$session_number[i] = x$session_number[i-1]
  }
}

# Activity within Session
for(i in seq(2, nrow(x))) {
  if(!is.na(x$tdiff[i]) &
     #  x$ID[i] == x$ID[i-1] &
     x$session_number[i] == x$session_number[i-1])
  {
    x$activity_within_session[i] = 
      x$activity_within_session[i-1] + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option could be:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

session_time_limit <- 30
df <- tibble(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
             Date = c(as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:12 UTC"), #a1
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:17:30 UTC"), #a2
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:57:12 UTC"), #a3
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 19:59:12 UTC"), #a4
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 20:11:12 UTC"), #b1
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 20:42:12 UTC"), #b2
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:15:42 UTC"), #c1
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:17:12 UTC"), #c2
                      as.POSIXct("2021-01-25 21:20:13 UTC"))) #c3

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(tdiff = replace_na(interval(lag(Date), Date)/dminutes(1), 0),
         session_number = cumsum(tdiff > session_time_limit) + 1) %>% 
  group_by(session_number, .add = T) %>% 
  mutate(activity_within_session = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   ID    Date                tdiff session_number activity_within_session
#>   <chr> <dttm>              <dbl>          <dbl>                   <int>
#> 1 a     2021-01-25 19:17:12  0                 1                       1
#> 2 a     2021-01-25 19:17:30  0.3               1                       2
#> 3 a     2021-01-25 19:57:12 39.7               2                       1
#> 4 a     2021-01-25 19:59:12  2                 2                       2
#> 5 b     2021-01-25 20:11:12  0                 1                       1
#> 6 b     2021-01-25 20:42:12 31                 2                       1
#> 7 c     2021-01-25 21:15:42  0                 1                       1
#> 8 c     2021-01-25 21:17:12  1.5               1                       2
#> 9 c     2021-01-25 21:20:13  3.02              1                       3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, tdiff := c(0, diff(as.numeric(Date)) / 60), by = ID
   ][, session_number := cumsum(tdiff > session_time_limit) + 1, by = ID
     ][, activity_within_session := rowid(ID, session_number)][]
```

or

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
df[, tdiff := c(0, diff(as.numeric(Date)) / 60), by = ID] %>% 
  .[, session_number := cumsum(tdiff > session_time_limit) + 1, by = ID] %>% 
  .[, activity_within_session := rowid(ID, session_number)] %>% 
  .[]
    
   ID                Date     tdiff session_number activity_within_session
1:  a 2021-01-25 19:17:12  0.000000              1                       1
2:  a 2021-01-25 19:17:30  0.300000              1                       2
3:  a 2021-01-25 19:57:12 39.700000              2                       1
4:  a 2021-01-25 19:59:12  2.000000              2                       2
5:  b 2021-01-25 20:11:12  0.000000              1                       1
6:  b 2021-01-25 20:42:12 31.000000              2                       1
7:  c 2021-01-25 21:15:42  0.000000              1                       1
8:  c 2021-01-25 21:17:12  1.500000              1                       2
9:  c 2021-01-25 21:20:13  3.016667              1                       3
```

Comment: This approach worked and was able to finish in a reasonable amount of time so is much better than my current approach! Using the cumsum for the session_number is quite clever - great thinking!

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)